# Can GitHub Pages be used as an image CDN

Tags: github, github-pages, cdn

I am aware that GitHub isn't meant to be used a CDN.

However, is there a downside to storing images in a GitHub repository, creating GitHub Pages and using it as an image CDN?

Answer (score 0):

##### [According to the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#usage-limits), Github Pages have **a *soft* bandwidth limit** of **100GB per month**.

That means, in theory, that you could serve e.g. 1MB images ~100,000 times per month, OR, 10MB images ~10,000 times per month (without taking local caching into account).

⚠ But there's also a notice about *rate limiting* possibly kicking in if too many requests are being made, but the docs say nothing about exactly *what* constitutes as too many, other than stating that *"these rate limits are not intended to interfere with **legitimate** uses of GitHub Pages"*.

---

In my personal opinion, there are far too many websites served using Github Pages, and many of them also serve images on their website (logos, banners, images, etc.). If those images can be served from Pages to possibly hundreds to thousands of users, I'm sure using Github Pages as an image CDN shouldn't pose a problem. But take this with a BIG grain of salt as I have *no* experience with these, nor with any possible rate limits being hit.

As an example, [**Bootstrap's** official website](https://getbootstrap.com/) seems to be served over Github Pages, and if you check [the code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/main/site), the image assets on the website seem to be served over Github (e.g. [image on website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png) | [same image on github repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/site/static/docs/5.3/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png)). Taking a glance at unofficial estimates of monthly website traffic ([here](https://www.semrush.com/website/getbootstrap.com/overview/) and [here](https://www.semrush.com/website/getbootstrap.com/overview/)), it seems like their website may get up to ~10 million visits per month! Even if 1 million of those are unique visitors, meaning the rest of the visits serve the locally cached images, that's still an insane amount, and that should be indicative of the upper limits you'd be working with :)